# Why is this function not able to return an integer due to no destination for result?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-13

I have a simple function that needs to return an integer from a select statement. This is it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate(_identityid integer, _postid integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    SELECT postid
    FROM post 
    WHERE
            postid = _postid
      AND
            identityid = _identityid;
END;
$$;
```

If I run the above function I get the following error:

> [42601] ERROR: query has no destination for
> result data Hint: If you want to discard the
> results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.

Why is there no destination for the result data? Why doesn't it just return the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Returning the same value that you pass as the parameter seems rather senseless to me to begin with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I suppose I just need something/anything to be returned for the function to report that the `postid` was validated so why not the `postid` itself.

Comment: I would prefer  a function that returns `true` or `false` rather than a value or `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) the result of a query needs to be stored somewhere.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate(_identityid integer, _postid integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
  l_result integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT postid
      into l_result
    FROM post 
    WHERE
            postid = _postid
      AND
            identityid = _identityid;
  return l_result;
END;
$$;
```

---

But to wrap a simple SELECT like that, using a `language sql` function is much better anyway and there you can return the result directly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate(_identityid integer, _postid integer) 
  RETURNS integer
  LANGUAGE sql
  stable
AS
$$
    SELECT postid
    FROM post 
    WHERE
            postid = _postid
      AND
            identityid = _identityid;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using `plpgsql` without using `RETURN` you need an `OUT` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.out_test(in_val integer, OUT out_val integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO out_val in_val + 1;
END;
$function$

select out_test(3);
 out_test 
----------
        4
```

Per the docs [Returning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING):

> The return value of a function cannot be left undefined. If control reaches the end of the top-level block of the function without hitting a RETURN statement, a run-time error will occur. This restriction does not apply to functions with output parameters and functions returning void, however. In those cases a RETURN statement is automatically executed if the top-level block finishes.